# How to access column with array(<bigint>) in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, mysql-workbench

If we want to access the column `abc` with array list(`<bigint>`) in it where the array which has negative number in it will result in previous letter in column `pqr`. Eg.,

```
|     abc           |      pqr         |     xyz    |
|-------------------|------------------|------------|
| [30,10,40,20]     |    A > B > C     |     C      |
| [10,20,300,40,-2] |   S > V > Z > U  |     Z      |
| [10,200,10,-5]    |    T > F > S     |     F      |
| [80,20,700,40]    |    H > C > D     |     D      |
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have an array type...

Comment: there is something called array<bigint>

Comment: Where did you see that? I can't find any documentation for MySQL about any `array<bigint>` type.